# Converting, slicing and concatenating columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a DataFrame with several columns, and I am trying to concatenate the month and year columns.

```py
    month    year
    5.0      2019.0
    5.0      2018.0
    4.0      2019.0
   12.0      2019.0
```

I have tried using the map() function to convert it into a string

```py
self.internal_df["month_year"] = self.internal_df["month"].map(str) + self.internal_df["year"].map(str)
```

The problem is that this just concatenates it to the following value:

```py
    month_year
     5.02019.0
     5.02018.0
     4.02019.0
    12.02019.0
```

and I want to make it look like this:

```py
    month_year
     5_2019
     5_2018
     4_2019
    12_2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is to convert the month and year columns to `int`s (`float`s don't make much sense anyways)

```
df[['month', 'year']] = df[['month', 'year']].astype(int)
```

And then cast them to `str` before concatenating them

```
df['month_year'] = df['month'].astype(str) + '_' + df['year'].astype(str)
```

Comment: I got the following error: `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Comment: Are there NaNs in your months or years? If so, why?

Comment: There should not be, I found that when pandas read the Excel-file, it put a row with NaN values at the end. I will fix that and run your code again.

Comment: It works! This is probably beginner level, but I am still struggling to understand pandas...